# java ResourceBundle.getBundle() undeterministic

Tags: java, classloader, java-ee-6

I have a very, very strange situation happening on our Java EE app running on WebSphere.

```
EAR
  --someJar.jar
  ----config/propfile.properties

  --WAR
    ----WEB-INF
      ------classes
        --------config/propfile.properties
```

When the application start up, ResourceBundle.getBundle("config/propfile.properties") seems to read someProperty from the WAR/WEB-INF/classes/config/propfile.properties.

However, after the app is up and running, ResourceBundle.getBundle("config/propfile.properties") seems to read someProperty from someJar.jar/config/propfile.properties instead.

I think that's how it's happening is because we have different values for someProperty on each file, and we got some error (due to the incorrect value from the someJar.jar/config/propfile.properties). According to Java EE spec, WEB-INF/classes should get loaded first before anything else?

Is it even possible? We could not replicate the problem in any of our lower environments.

The `WAR/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is ...`Class-Path: lib/begin...lib/end someJar.jar`

Comment: Do you have other modules like an ejb module in your ear file?

Comment: Yes, there is. I don't include it here because `propfile.properties` file is not included in this ejb module. The ejb jar is on the same level as the someJar.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second call to `ResourceBundle.getBundle("config/propfile.properties")` is from a class in the ejb module, it would no have access to `WAR/WEB-INF/classes/config/propfile.properties`.  This is because each module has a different class loader.

Download the ee spec at the following link (or the corresponding spec for your javaee standard).

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-6.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

In this version the relevant section is EE.8.3

Comment: Spot on. Yes the 2nd call is invoked from the ejb module.

Comment: Actually, last weekend, for some reason there's on error. Look like 2nd call to `ResourceBundle.getBundle("config/propfile.properties")` was successful with no error. Now I'm really puzzle. WAS 8, running on JDK 1.6.